# Historical (pre-war) data on cities and towns in Germany

Tags: city, historical, census, germany

**What I do:**

I'm trying to find and merge city-level data from various time periods:
~1900, ~1930 and ~1990. I already have data on election outcomes, and a few related measures.

**What's difficult:**

Obviously some cities merged, new places were founded after 1900, and again others are in nowadays Poland or France. 
I am mainly interested in finding data on population densities and further demographics, but would need to know in detail whether some data point pertains to exactly the same unit of observations.

*Example:* Older data might have an entry for "Ebingen" in Baden-Württemberg. In 1975 Albstadt was founded and Ebingen bekame a part of Albstadt so more recent data will have Albstadt not Ebingen, but Albstadt also contains other places.

**What I need:**

Is there any public dataset available that provides

- provides information on such changes,
- provides pre-war demographics, and ideally
- links pre-var town names to today's municipality-IDs (GKZ)?

If there's data fitting only one of these points I'm grateful too.

Comment: Can it be just gridded data? (e.g. on a 0.1 x 0.1 degree grid)

Comment: That would be what? around 10kmX10km in Germany? I guess this would circumvent the problem of having to consider mergers and splits, but then again it would make it more difficult to match data from multiple sources, no?

Comment: A colleagues uses gridded population density data for his work (he is currently on holiday). I am not sure if these data are available for before 1944 but I will ask him when he is back and post an answer if the data are available.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but geonames sometimes contains historical place names as "alternate names". As a note, geonames still lists both Albstadt and Ebingen at almost-but-not-quite the same location. Perhaps you could use some sort of polygon-level filtering for Germany's older shape and then distance-filtering re considering two cities equivalent?

Comment: The German language wikipedia has lots of information on these questions, but unfortunately not in a format that is easy to process automatically.